# How to use loop variable in lambda expression

Tags: python

I am trying to add multiple numbered commands to a Tkinter menu using a for loop. When a command is invoked its number is supposed to be used as an argument to the command function. The following code does not work because i is evaluated when the command is invoked, which is after the loop has finished. This means that the argument passed to function1 is always 15 whereas I inted to pass the number that is displayed on the command label. Is there any way to accomplish this?

NOTE: The labeling works as intended, producing 16 options labeled 0 to 15

```
newMenu = Menu(menuButtonInstance)
for i in range(16):
    newMenu.add_command(label = '%s'%i,
                        command = lambda:function1(i))
menuButtonInstance.config(menu = newMenu)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

One often used way of handling `lambda`'s late binding is by giving lambda an argument with a default value set to the changing variable:

```
    newMenu.add_command(label='{0}'.format(i),
                        command=lambda x=i: function1(x))
```

Another possibility is to use [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from `functools`:

```
    newMenu.add_command(label='{0}'.format(i),
                        command=partial(function1, i))
```

(Note that [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends not using space characters on each side of `=` when used in keyword arguments. On the other hand you *should* put space characters around all operators, like `%` in your example)

Comment: The `partial` approach is much better IMHO. The default argument trick is a quirky hack that leaves the mistaken impression that the default argument is meant to be replaceable.